Unable to reset local admin account password
I have an iMac (Late 2014 27" Retina 5K, macOS 11.7.10) in need of password recovery. The user knows their Apple ID credentials, but when following the reset option using their Apple ID, their credentials are not accepted with a general "shake" (wrong password) error.
They are able to use their computer otherwise as a password is not required on login. We also tried changing the Apple ID password, removing entries from Keychain Access, and running "resetpassword" which does not exist. We also tried booting into recovery environment and were unable to use dscl tool or passwd.
Thanks in advance.


Apple ID credentials not accepted > talk to Apple
